# Where can download a DEM for whole world in a single low resolution image?

Tags: dem, blendergis

I work in Blender to make Earth globe and I need elevation data for whole earth with low spatial resolution to make relief as a terrain.

Comment: try etopo2 85Mb zipped: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO2/ETOPO2v2-2006/ETOPO2v2c/netCDF/